# Merging Two Ranges as One Range in Google App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, merge, range

I have a google app script.

**code.gs**

```
const doGet = _ => {
  
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1FJtOQZAN_SIOYHybA9FXbJ_ngoRy38KTvo1hZu7SEUs");

  const sheetA = ss.getSheetByName("SYLLABUSC");
  const rangeA = sheetA.getRange("E1:E5");

  const sheetB = ss.getSheetByName("SHEETB");
  const rangeB = sheetB.getRange("A1:A3");

  const html = rangeA.getDisplayValues().join("\n");
  
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(html).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);
}
```

By above I'm getting **TextOutput** from **SheeA Range** only.

But I want both ranges one by one, i.e.
SheetA Range and then SheetB Range.

How to merge these ..?

**Update :**

By the Answer provided, the **Code.gs file** modified like below.

```
const doGet = _ => {
  
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1FJtOQZAN_SIOYHybA9FXbJ_ngoRy38KTvo1hZu7SEUs");

  const sheetA = ss.getSheetByName("SYLLABUSC");
  const rangeA = sheetA.getRange("E1:E5").getDisplayValues();

  const sheetB = ss.getSheetByName("SHEETB");
  const rangeB = sheetB.getRange("A1:A3").getDisplayValues();

  const html = rangeA.concat(rangeB).join("\n");
  
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(html).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);
}
```

Here is **[My Web App](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycby5Hzd00J2SeqrbAXSkypIU7YSgVi5g3MxVpHz5wmGvBO8H2MlXX1fBwNd8xhcLgXfRvQ/exec)**

Comment: What are you doing with the  data?

Comment: I'm using the Web App URL as ```script source file``` for my wordpress hosted site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this:

```
const html = rangeA.getDisplayValues().join("\n");
```

With this:

```
let html = rangeA.getDisplayValues().concat(rangeB.getDisplayValues());
html = html.join("\n");
```

Comment: Sorry, never used Wordpress.

Comment: That's ok fine. No Problem : )

Answer (score 1):

Merge Ranges:

```
function mergeRanges() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1R5Wgq4okSWz0d159X5kPvOk8W1T_6eZ2kwoq5kdjO0w");
  const sheetA = ss.getSheetByName("SYLLABUSC");
  const vsa = sheetA.getRange("C1:C6").getDisplayValues();
  const sheetB = ss.getSheetByName("SHEETB");
  const vsb = sheetB.getRange("A1:A3").getDisplayValues();
  const html = [vsa, vsb].reduce((a, c, i) => {
    c.forEach(arr => a += arr.join('\n'))
    return a;
  }, "")
  Logger.log(html);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(html).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);
}
```

Comment: not working, getting error ```Script function not found: doGet```

Comment: It worked for me maybe you need change sheet names and spreadsheet

Comment: yes I tried with current sheet names. forgotten to rename sheets, Thank You : )